# Barcodes in PDFs generated by BIRT

Tags: eclipse, birt

I'm trying to simply include a barcode in a report generated by BIRT.

Here's what I have:

- BIRT Runtime 4.4.2
- Eclipse BIRT Project 4.6
- Eclipse Neon.3 Release 4.6.3

First I tried to simply set the font on a standard text item.  This works fine in the designer, but when the pdf is generated, the text item just shows the text in the standard font, not the barcode font that I set in the designer.

I have also tried plugins from these guys:

- [OnBarcode.com](http://www.onbarcode.com/eclipse_birt/) - I was using Eclipse 2019-11 but the Barcode item didn't appear at all in the pallete when editing a report.  I had to go back to Neon to get the item to show.  I was then able to ad a barcode item into the report and save the report. Then when my server code tried to generate a barcode, BIRT just crashed.
- [BusinessRefinery.com](http://www.businessrefinery.com/products/barcode_birt/main.html) - Even in Eclipse Neon the Barcode item didn't show in the palette.  I couldn't do anything with this.

I know where the plugins folder is in my Eclipse, so I guess it's just a versioning issue somewhere with teh plugins.  Also I can see that the plugins are stored in a completely different place in Eclipse 2019-11 so it's no surprise that the two plugins I mention above don't work because I would guess that the plugin architecture has changed.

I would love to hear from anybody who has achieved either of these two:

1. Got a non-standard font to appear in a pdf generated by BIRT.
2. Got a barcode plugin that works with the versions of BIRT and Eclipse that I mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We are using the Java libraries from ID automation and generate images on the fly by using the Java libraries with Javascript from inside BIRT.
This is not as elegant as a plugin, but it works fine.
For QR-Codes, we are using Google's ZXing library in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this PLUGIN (source code): https://code.google.com/archive/p/birt-barcode-extension/

It's not very sophisticated, but you can insert / EDIT the barcodes on the template with a "default" preview.

It relies on ZXing (you must get it from GITHUB)